# How do I fix my palm tree?

Tags: diseases, palm, rot

My palm tree has some holes and odd texture at the bottom. Someone told me it could be rot or a disease. I am looking for some answers as to how to fix it. It could be drainage which I am fixing. Is there anything else I could do to help save this tree?

[image: 1]